# Acronym display using glossaries package

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

This is probably a very simple formatting issue with the "see" field.  After I run "makeglossaries mwe" on mwe.tex below, the list of acronyms contains misformatted entries like

```
EC Espoir de chelem. 1, Glossary: ECGlossary:]SansECg
```

I've tried adding extra brackets around the "see" field without success.

MWE is

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, book]{memoir}

\RequirePackage[xindy,acronym]{glossaries}%

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ECg}{name={EC},description={Espoir de chelem}}
\newglossaryentry{EC}{type=\acronymtype,name={EC},description={Espoir de chelem},first={Espoir de chelem (EC)\glsadd{ECg}},see=[Glossary:]{ECg}}

\newglossaryentry{SansECg}{name={\ensuremath{\sim}EC}, description={Sans espoir de chelem}}
\newglossaryentry{SansEC}{type=\acronymtype,name={\ensuremath{\sim}EC},description={Sans espoir de chelem},first={Sans espoir de chelem (\ensuremath{\sim}EC)\glsadd{SansECg}},see=[Glossary:]{SansECg}}

\begin{document} 

First use \gls{EC}\\
Subsequent use \gls{EC}\\

First use \gls{SansEC}\\
Subsequent use \gls{SansEC}\\

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

Edit:  I've tried reformatting the entries and now I've a version of the MWE that works (MWE1 below).  The problem still remains though because when I paste the item definitions below into my live glossary, delete all the associated glossary files and do what should be a clean re-run of my live system, the misformat still appears :-(

MWE1:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, book]{memoir}

%\RequirePackage[pdftex,unicode=true,psdextra,colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,hyperfootnotes=false,linktoc=all]{hyperref}%

\RequirePackage[xindy,acronym]{glossaries}%

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{ecg}{name={EC}, description={Espoir de chelem}}
\newglossaryentry{ec}{type=\acronymtype, name={EC}, description={Espoir de chelem}, first={Espoir de chelem (EC)\glsadd{ecg}}, see=[Glossary:]{ecg}}

\begin{document} 

First use \gls{ec}\\
Subsequent use \gls{ec}\\
\newpage 
Subsequent use \gls{ec}\\


\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary[type=main]

\end{document}
```

I thought for a while it was related to an interaction with hyperref, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  Initially, I thought there might be a language issue but the first MWE is only English and the live log file shows the French language module automatically being loaded.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that before but it seems that `xindy` has a problem with `see` starting with the optional part. It works fine with `makeindex`. If all your cross-references start with `Glossary:` then a simple workaround is to omit the `[Glossary:]` part and just redefine `\seename` before the glossaries (`\renewcommand{\seename}{Glossary:}`).

Comment: Thanks Nicola.  As you say, it works fine with makeindex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem only occurs with `xindy` and not with `makeindex`. It's not immediately obvious, but it's caused by `xindy` merging two entries. The `.acn` file shows the input that `xindy` is processing. The first two lines are:

```
(indexentry :tkey (("EC" "\\glossentry{EC}") ) :xref ("[Glossary:]{ECg}") :attr "see" )
(indexentry :tkey (("\\ensuremath {\\sim }EC" "\\glossentry{SansEC}") ) :xref ("[Glossary:]{SansECg}") :attr "see" )
```

In the first case, the sort value is `EC` (the first element in the `:tkey` list). In the second case, the sort value is `\\ensuremath {\\sim }EC`, but `xindy` discards LaTeX markup so this sort value is converted into `EC`. This is identical to the first entry, so `xindy` merges them, and the location list ends up with

```
\glsseeformat[Glossary:]{ECg}[Glossary:]{SansECg}{}
```

The syntax for `\glsseeformat` is `[`*tag*`]{`*label*`}{`*location*`}` so the `[` following `{ECg}` is treated as the *location* part, which is ignored. The remainder is the trailing text you found in your document. This merging of entries with duplicate sort values is a quirk of `xindy`. To avoid it, you need to make sure that the sort value is different by adding the `sort` key. For example:

```
\newglossaryentry{SansEC}{
 sort={~EC},
 type=\acronymtype,
 name={\ensuremath{\sim}EC},
 description={Sans espoir de chelem},
 first={Sans espoir de chelem (\ensuremath{\sim}EC)\glsadd{SansECg}},
 see=[Glossary:]{SansECg}}
```

Comment: Excellent answer - much appreciated.